# Storybook named default export

Tags: reactjs, storybook

Is it possible to use named default export in storybook file?

.... preview.stories.js

```js
export default {
  title: "Widget/Preview",
  argTypes: {
    variant: {
      options: ["inpage", "dialog"],
      control: {
        type: "inline-radio",
      },
    },
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found

"const Default = {...."
then
"export default Default" works for me.